# Can I easily override an (STL) iterator's category?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

Right now, I have a class that can satisfy an API requirement with a random-access iterator.  However, I can envision a situation where the implementation will change and only a forward iterator can be provided.

Therefore, I would like to restrict callers from using the random-access functionality.  I know I can write my own implementation (e.g. restricted_bar_iterator), but was wondering if there is anything simpler (i.e. requiring less coding).

```
class BAR { ... };

class FOO {
public:
    // Bad...clients may expect 'bar_iterator' to be random access...
    typedef std::vector<BAR>::iterator bar_iterator;

    bar_iterator begin_bar() const;
    bar_iterator end_bar() const;

    // Possible solution here!
    class restricted_bar_iterator :
        public std::iterator< std::forward_iterator_tag, BAR > { ... };
};


void baz()
{
    FOO foo;
    bar_iterator it = foo.begin_bar() + 5; // want a compile time error here!
}
```

Comment: I'd try the hardest possible to avoid this situation, but I *really* wanted to do it, I'd go for public inheritance of `vector::[const_]iterator` and explicit specialization of `std::iterator_traits`, because this is what takes the least amount of code. I won't put this as an answer because it is really preferable to avoid this completely.

Comment: Inherit from `std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, T>` and define all the mthods you need so its behaves exactly as you would expect.

Comment: @AlexandreC., even if `vector<BAR>::iterator` is a class type, you still need to replace at least the two `operator++` overloads, otherwise they return the base type, and just specializing `iterator_traits` doesn't stop the code above from attempting to use RandomAccessIterator operations even if the category says ForwardIterator

Comment: @JonathanWakely: You can hide members in the derived class (both operator++), or you can also use private inheritance and `using` directives. I find this much clearer than inheriting `std::iterator` and forwarding functions manually. Also good point about whether `vector::iterator` has class type, but there might be something in the standard which implies it.

Comment: @AlexandreC.: the standard certainly allows `std::vector<T>::iterator` to be `T*`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Thanks for the information. May I ask you then why are vector iterators typically not implemented as pointers ?

Comment: In my opinion, encapsulation requires definition of a custom iterator class, as making the container's iterator type visible to the outside makes an implementation detail public.

Comment: @AlexandreC.: One of the reasons is that many standard libraries have a debug mode where the iterator operations are checked. In that case, the iterators needed to be class types. However, making it a pointer in non-debug mode slightly change what can be done. For example, if the iterator is a class type, the expression `--vec.end()` is legal on a non-empty `vec`. If the iterator type is `T*` the code won't even compile. However, it would be confusing if code used during debugging failed to compile when disabling debugging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example using [Boost Iterator Adaptor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/iterator/doc/iterator_adaptor.html). I used `int` instead of `BAR`.

```
#include <boost/iterator/iterator_adaptor.hpp>
#include <vector>

struct iterator :
    public boost::iterator_adaptor<
        iterator,                    // the name of our class, see docs for details
        std::vector<int>::iterator,  // underlying base iterator
        boost::use_default,          // for value type
        boost::forward_traversal_tag // all the boilerplate for this!
    >
{
     // need this to convert from vector::iterator to ours
     explicit iterator(std::vector<int>::iterator i)
      : iterator::iterator_adaptor_(i) {}
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    iterator it(v.begin());
    ++it;    // OK
    it += 1; // ERROR
}
```

This effectively uses a `std::vector<T>::iterator` as a base class, but only allows operations that are defined for forward iterators. The downside are the error messages - they aren't very pretty.

Answer (score 3):

You definitely have to do *some* coding, but you might be able to inherit from the underlying type to get most of the functionality, just overriding the operations you don't want to work, either by defining them as deleted in C++11 or making them private and unimplemented in C++03:

```
class FOO {
    // Bad...clients may expect 'bar_iterator' to be random access...
    typedef std::vector<BAR>::iterator bar_iterator_impl;

public:
    // Possible solution here!
    struct bar_iterator : bar_iterator_impl {
      bar_iterator& operator++() {
        ++static_cast<bar_iterator_impl&>(*this);
        return *this;
      }
      bar_iterator operator++(int) {
        bar_iterator copy(*this);
        ++*this;
        return copy;
      }

      typedef std::forward_iterator_tag iterator_category;    
      typedef std::iterator_traits<bar_iterator_impl>::value_type value_type;
      typedef std::iterator_traits<bar_iterator_impl>::difference_type difference_type;
      typedef std::iterator_traits<bar_iterator_impl>::pointer    pointer;
      typedef std::iterator_traits<bar_iterator_impl>::reference  reference;

    private:
      friend void operator+(bar_iterator const&, long);
      friend void operator+(long, bar_iterator const&);
      friend void operator-(bar_iterator const&, long);
      friend void operator-(long, bar_iterator const&);
    };

    bar_iterator begin_bar() const;
    bar_iterator end_bar() const;
};
```

However this only works if `std::vector<BAR>::iterator` is a class type, and it could be a pointer, in which case it cannot be derived from. To be portable, you'd need to define the whole iterator API yourself.